# Assembly Language: Floating-point Arithmetic

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm not understanding how to get my program to do floating-point arithmetic with the FPU Stack. I've tried declaring REAL8 variables and fld the variables into the FPU stack but I continue to get the following error:

[Error code A2050: real or BCD number not allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brvOZ.png)

Code:

```
    fstp dword ptr [esi]  ; pops top value of stack and stores 32-bit memory location pointed to by esi

    mov eax, 18.5         ; moves value 18.5 to eax
    mov ebx, 100          ; moves value 100 to ebx
    mul ebx               ; multiples ebx by eax (18.5 * 100) and stores in eax
    div ecx               ; divides eax by ecx (1850 / 100) and stores in eax
    mov edx, eax          ; moves eax into edx, edx now holds (1850 / 100)
    mov eax, esi          ; moves input value address into eax
    add eax, edx          ; adds edx to input value and storing in eax (1850/100 + input value)
    mov edx, 8.75         ; moves value 8.75 to edx
    mov ebx, 100          ; moves value 100 to ebx
    mul ebx               ; multiples ebx by edx (18.75 * 100)
    div ecx               ; divides edx by ecx (875 / 100) and stores in edx
    add eax, edx          ; adds edx to eax (875 / 100 + input value + tax calculation)
    mov edx, eax          ; moves eax to edx (input value + tax____ + tax _____) to edx
    mov esi, eax          ; moves eax to esi (input value + tax_____ + tax ____)

    fld dword ptr [esi]   ; loads 32-bit value esi is pointing to onto the FPU stack
    fadd dword ptr [edi]  ; adds (input value + tax_____ + tax ____) to value pointed to by edi and storing result in edi
    fstp dword ptr [edi]  ; pops top value off FPU stack and stores in 32-bit memory location pointed to by edi
```

I can add the rest of the code if it's needed, I'm just guessing that the problem lies somewhere in here.

Comment: `edx` is an integer register, not floating-point.  Also, your `fld dword ptr [esi]` is a load from memory using ESI as a pointer.  But ESI is the sum of quotient and remainder from an integer `div`.  (`add eax, edx` / `mov esi, eax`).  That's not going to make a valid pointer.  Also doesn't seem useful, perhaps you thought the remainder was the fractional part?  remainder / divisor is the fractional part; `div` does integer math not FP.

Comment: Often you don't need FP, just scale your values by 100 or something, so `8.75` becomes `875`.  And you can divide by 100 to get the `8` and the `75` part separately.

Comment: Everything on integer registers is an integer operation.  I am not sure why you try to do floating point operations with integers registers.  It does not make sense.  You'll have to completely rewrite the code to use the FP stack and FP instructions.